# Странное поведение Intersection Observer API | Не фиксирует видимый блок

Tags: javascript, observer

Даже если два блока видно, в консоли показывается только один элемент.
Что странно, только при старте скрипта он показывает два элемента сразу, при прокрутке только один и никак больше.

```js
const options = {
 threshold: 1.0
}
const targets = document.querySelectorAll('.blocks .block');
const value = document.querySelector('p b');

const callback = (entries, observer) => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
  if (!entry.isIntersecting) return;
  console.log(entry.target.innerHTML);
  value.innerHTML = entry.target.innerHTML;
  });
}

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
targets.forEach(target => observer.observe(target));
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}
.container p {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}
.container .blocks {
  width: 50%;
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}
.container .blocks .block {
  margin: 10px 0;
  height: 35vh;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <p>Value: <b></b></p>
 <div class="blocks">
  <div class="block">[1] block</div>
  <div class="block">[2] block</div>
  <div class="block">[3] block</div>
  <div class="block">[4] block</div>
  <div class="block">[5] block</div>
  <div class="block">[6] block</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а зачем больше одного раза сигнализировать о том, что блок в поле видимости?

Comment: @hu-fo не совсем понял о чем вы